# Removing "New " button from Case comment related list

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, administration

On case record page, there is case comment related list.I want to remove "New" button from this related list. Unable to do it from page layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is currently unavailable at the moment.  Kindly review and vote for this feature [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq29AAC). Also you might want to check and vote for the [Permissions on Case Comments](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpYo) feature as well.

Thanks